# App not detecting sdcard data

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-grand

I have recently downloaded NFS Most Wanted on my Samsung Galaxy Grand i9082.... the problem is that when I copied the data folder I downloaded into Android>>> Data>>> and I installed the apk file and when I check the app status it shows sd card data-0.00 B

Comment: What is this data folder you downloaded? You wouldn't normally have to copy a data folder yourself when installing an app. Are you trying to install the app from an *unofficial* source, or to copy a friend's save game, or something like that?

Comment: @Dan,it seems like he is installing it from an unofficial source. 
Most of the game data is stored in `/sdcard/Android/obb`, make sure you are pasting it in the correct/intended folder.
Some data is stored in `/sdcard/Android/data`. Few games have data stored in both the locations.

Answer (score 1):

dont put the data files in obb.
instead put it in the sd card/android/data folder 
it works

Answer (score -1):

First install game and play it once.  Then paste your downloaded data folder to Android-Data.  Hope it helps